# One write method for all, FilterWriter

Tags: java, java-io

I am implementing my own [FilterWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterWriter.html). Is there one write/append method of the FilterWriter, that will be called for by all the other write/append implementations? 
So I don't have to override all methods and just override e.g. the `void write(int c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you extend a FilterWriter, you need to override its three methods:

```
public void write(char[] buffer, int offset, int count) throws IOException;
public void write(int oneChar) throws IOException;
public void write(String str, int offset, int count) throws IOException;
```

If you implement a Writer class, you need to override a single method.

```
public abstract void write(char[] buf, int offset, int count) throws IOException;
```

You can find this methods in Java source code.

Comment: One additional question to your solution: how come that a write(String str) on my FilterWriter implementation will call write(String str, int offset, int count)?

Comment: It's over way around. In Writer class all other methods call write(String str, int offset, int count). FilterWriter overrides three methods (see above) and forwards the calls to the Writer instance given in FilterWriter's constructor. If you implement FilterWriter, you need to override these three methods.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there one write/append method of the FilterWriter, that will be
>   called for by all the other write/append implementations?

Yes, [write(char[] buf, int offset, int count)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29). But it's not recommanded to use only this one, because if you want write primitives like `int`'s you have to cast it to a `char-Array`.
That's why the other methods like `write(int)` are there to do the casting. Otherwise you will have to write code like this;

```
write(new char[]{(char)myInt, ...}, 0, 1);
```

This will be even worse if you wanna write a mix of primitives and Strings.

The append(...) methods just call the write(...) methods. Like this:

```
public Writer append(CharSequence csq) throws IOException {
    if (csq == null)
        write("null");
    else
        write(csq.toString());
   return this;
}
```

These should be overriden too.
Long story short, at the end you will have a lot more code and headaches if you just use one `write` or `append` method. Better implement them all properly while designing your class.

Comment: No. All three implementations call `out.write(...)` whatever, the corresponding write method of the nested stream. They don't call each other, ergo you have to override all three.

Answer (score -1):

Pass true as a second argument to FileWriter to turn on "append" mode.

```
fout = new FileWriter("filename.txt", true);
```

[FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) usage reference

Comment: The question is "is there one write/append *method*" [my emphasis].